# Parallel MATLAB and logging

Tags: logging, matlab, parallel-processing

I am running an experiment distributed over several computers using the Parallel computing toolbox. I want to be able to produce a log of the progress of the experiment (or of any error occurring) and save this info in a file while the processes are running. What is the standard way to do it?

EDIT:

1. I use embarrassingly parallel
2. I want only one file for all the workers (I have a network drive that can be accessed from all the machine)

My main concern is having a file opened for append by several workers. Do I risk losing messages, or having an error opening the file?

Comment: Are you doing embarrassingly parallel?  Do you want one file for each worker, or just one on the client machine.  How often do you want this file updated, just one per task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When multiple processes output to a single file, you *could* run into some potential problems, like messages being overwritten or intermingled. I've had this happen with programs in other languages (like C), and I *assume* the same problem could arise in MATLAB, but I freely admit I could be wrong about this. Assuming I'm *not* wrong...

If you want to reliably output data from multiple worker processes to a single log file while the processes are running, one way to do this is to make one process be responsible for all the file operations (i.e. a "master" process). The "master" process would collect messages from the other workers (i.e. "slaves") and output this data to the log file.

Since I don't know what specifically you are having each process do, it's hard to suggest specific code changes to make. Here are some steps and sample code for how you might do this in MATLAB. These code samples assume you are running the same function (**process_fcn**) on each process:

- The "master" process first has to open the file. This code (using the [labindex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labindex.html) function) should be run at the beginning of **process_fcn**:

  ```
  if (labindex == 1),
    fid = fopen('log.txt','at');  %# Open text file for appending
  end
  ```
- While each process is running, you can collect any data that needs to be output to the log file in a variable called **data**, which stores a string or character array. This data could be error messages captured within a [try-catch block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bq9l46c-1.html) or any other data that you would want to be in the log file.
- At periodic points in **process_fcn** (either when major tasks are completed or within a loop of computation), you would have to have each process check for data that needs to be output (i.e. **data** is not empty) and have that data sent to the "master" process. The "master" process would then collect and print these messages from other processes, along with any of its own. Here's a sample of how this might be done (using the functions [labBarrier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labbarrier.html), [labProbe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labprobe.html), [labSend](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labsend.html), and [labReceive](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labreceive.html)):

  ```
  labBarrier;  %# All processes are synchronized here
  if (labindex == 1),  %# This is done by the "master"
    if ~isempty(data),
      fprintf(fid,'%s\n',data);  %# Print "master" data
    end
    pause(1);  %# Wait a moment for "slaves" to send messages
    while labProbe,  %# Loop while messages are available
      data = labReceive;  %# Get data from "slaves"
      fprintf(fid,'%s\n',data);
    end
  else  %# This is done by the "slaves"
    if ~isempty(data),
      labSend(data,1);  %# Send data to the "master"
    end
  end
  data = '';  %# Clear data
  ```

  The call to [PAUSE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pause.html) is there to ensure that the calls to **labSend** for each "slave" process occur before the "master" starts looking for sent messages.
- Finally, the "master" process has to close the file. This code should be run at the end of **process_fcn**:

  ```
  if (labindex == 1),
    fclose(fid);
  end
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure about the labBarrier function (because my jobs don't have the same running time). But this give me a good starting point.

Comment: If your jobs have vastly different running times then synchronizing them for outputting data gets tricky. I'm unsure if labSend is a *blocking* call (process waits for a matching receive) or *non-blocking* call (message is buffered and the process moves on, whether a receive is posted or not). My above code assumes it's blocking... if it's non-blocking it would probably simplify things for you (i.e. no labBarrier or PAUSE would be needed).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are doing embarrassingly parallel (that is the job and task structure) and that you want the log file updated at the end of each task, I would use the [taskFinish](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/taskfinish.html) callback.

You could also just write to a file somehow in the middle of your task as you would in MATLAB normally, but I think you are asking about callbacks at the end of the task.