# How can we implement a parallel pipeline using 3 workers in one computer in MATLAB?

Tags: parallel-processing

Please I have a question:

I would like to used 3 workers (cores) to implement 3 functions in a parallel as pipeline, i.e. the first worker create the data, do some process(fun-add), and sends the results (x) to the first buffer/queue/matrix. Then, the second worker receives the data from the first buffer, do some process (fun-mult), and send the results (y) to the second buffer. The third worker receive the data, do some process (fun-double) and print the output(z). In the following attach the picture show the situation.

[image]
My question is that: How can we implement these three functions in parallel pipeline ?

Please, any idea how to solve this problem?

Kind regards Ammar

Comment: if worker2 needs the full dataset produced by worker one, then the problem would be sequential. As far as I know, the parallel framework in Matlab doesn't allow such parallel construct, instead MPI/openMP libraries in C can definitely do that http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-introduction/.
This being said, I came across an MPI toolbox for Matlab, have a look here http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/cybersec/softwaretools/pmatlab/pmatlab.html

Comment: Dear Marouen, Thank you very much for these information. Yes, worker2 needs part of the results which are saved in queue. At the same time, worker3 needs part of the results. As illustrated in the figure, the results will save in the queue to give the chance of parallel pipeline. Please, if you have any further idea, could you help. Thanks. Ammar.

Comment: have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075387/parallel-matlab-and-logging

Comment: Intel TBB pipeline will do the job for you https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Working_on_the_Assembly_Line_pipeline.html